# Fixed header on scroll but submenu needs to push content down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a fixed header for the level1 menu, but the submenu needs to push the rest of the page down when clicked on level1.

If I make the header position fixed obviously the content will not be pushed down and the submenu will overlap the content (as well as the menu).

How do people usually solve this issue? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/L3xh3av1/

js:

```
$(".menu").on("click",function(){
$(".submenu").slideToggle();
})
```

html:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="menu">menu</div>
    <div class="submenu">submenu</div>
  </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>content needs to be pushed down</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.header{
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.menu{
    height:70px;
    background:blue;
}
.submenu{
    height:70px;
    background:yellow;
    display:none;
}
.content{
    background: purple;
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}
.content p{
    color:black;
}
.page{
    height:3000px;
}
```

Comment: If you haven't ruled out 3rd party libs, bootstrap is an option. Gives you a nice navbar.

Comment: Looking at your example, I would think you would always want the content to be below the header...am I right?

Comment: When you say "fix header for level 1 menu", do you mean "fixed and always visible" even when page content scrolls, or just that its height is fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version have a fixed header where the submenu push the content down.

To make it work properly I changed your css a little where your `.menu` is fixed and your `.header` got a `padding` to move the non fixed stuff down into view.

```js
$(".menu").on("click",function(){
$(".submenu").slideToggle();
})
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
.header{
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
.menu{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background:blue;
}
.submenu{
    height:70px;
    background:yellow;
    display:none;
}
.content{
    background: purple;
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}
.content p{
    color:black;
}
.page{
    height:3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menu">menu</div>
        <div class="submenu">submenu</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>content needs to be pushed down</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this for solution http://jsfiddle.net/L3xh3av1/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="menu">menu</div>
    <div class="submenu">submenu</div>
    <div class="header-red">Header</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>content needs to be pushed down</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.header-red {
    background: red;
    height: 70px;
}
.menu{
    height:70px;
    background:blue;
}
.submenu{
    background:yellow;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.show {
    height: 70px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.content{
    background: purple;
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}
.content p{
    color:black;
}
.page{
    height:3000px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".menu").on("click",function(){
  $(".submenu").toggleClass('show');
});
```

**EDIT:**

Solution 2 - Not fixed header http://jsfiddle.net/L3xh3av1/5/

SOlution 3 - Header change http://jsfiddle.net/L3xh3av1/6/

Comment: but OP want rest of the page to be push down in you demo only header height is changed

Comment: How can you push page content down when you scroll and your header or menu is fixed on top of window. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: by setting margin or padding to content

Comment: @Gene R can you create fiddle and show what you mean?

Comment: next answer did the thing

Comment: @Gene R But when you scroll more down the page and click on menu nothing changes

Comment: It does, you just don't see it using a solution like asked for. Scroll up and you'll see submenu were toggled

Comment: Yea i guess i didn't understand what op was asking for, if that's it that is great.

Comment: @Nenad Vracar +1 Upvote for you first solution since pushing content down and making header fixed is not possible at time what i like is instead of content make header push down

Comment: Yepp, nothing wrong with your solution, I actually would do it myself this way.